# php.ini is overwritten locally whenever project is run

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, visual-studio-2013

Okay, I've been having issues with PDO connection strings in a new VS.PHP 3.3 project.

I have found the main, apparent, cause of this is that in phpinfo() PDO drivers shows "no value".

Having scoured the net I followed all instructions and found the in php.ini

extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

was remarked out.  I unremarked and saved.  This made no difference.  I then noticed that

Loaded Configuration File linked to "E:\Website\Website\php.ini

which is the local project folder.  Unable to see a file here I assumed it was hidden and, sure enough, when I showed the hidden file, there it was.  I opened and noticed that, as above, the extension was remarked out.  I amended, saved, re-ran phpinfo() and there was no change.  In going back into the local php.ini all changes had reverted back.

I have changed the three php.ini files that are saved in "PHP 5.2", "PHP 5.3" and "PHP 5.4" and none of them reflect the local php.ini.

I have no idea where to go next.  Really hoping someone can point out my deliberate mistake.

Comment: You restarted php-fpm or your webserver (depending on your setup) after making changes to php.ini, right?

Comment: The server, as such, is only the standard Apache that's launched by VS.  How would you restart php-fpm on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panic over, problem solved.

For anyone who suffers from the same problem, this is how it is solved....

In the PHP 5.4 directory there is a config file "php-xdebug".  This is where you need to change the extensions.  This is where VS was overwriting from.